# Pointer Events WxWidgets WebView

Tags: c++, webview, wxwidgets

I'm currently integrating a web based map engine (OpenLayers) with wxWidgets webView, the map currently expects pointer events but the the webView only triggers mouse events, I wanted to ask if the wxWebView supports pointer events and if yes how to enable them. I also tried using **Pointer Events Polyfill** but the webView still unable to generate pointer events.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: which back-end - IE, Mozilla, Chromium, WebKitGTK, Safari? What platform? What wx version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem by using the latest wxWidgets release (3.1.4) that comes with the wxWebView with the Edge Chromium backend